# window.history.pushState removes "?" from query string

Tags: javascript, url-parameters, pushstate

I have a page that already uses get paramters

https://example.com/?name=Dimitar

Now i have an onClick function

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

function updateURL(skill, value) {
    urlParams.set(skill, value)
    window.history.pushState({}, '', urlParams);
}
```

that i want to update the query string wiuth additional parameters. And it does that but it strips the "?" from my query string and my URL becomes https://example.com/name=Dimitar&newparam=1 the page goes to

Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

Comment: What is `urlParams`? Because if it's just a `URLSearchParams`, it's not enough; it has to be a `URL`.

Comment: sorry, adding as an edit